# Why do I have to redo a try-except statement when calling a function that does this exactly?

Tags: python, function, exception, methods

I have the following problem:
I have specified a method for a given class which handles two different Errors with the same user-defined exception (see the method below).

```
def get_route(self, source, target):

    try:
        n = nx.shortest_path(self.graph, source, target)
        return n

    except (nx.NetworkXNoPath, nx.NodeNotFound):
        raise NoSuchFlight
```

So now, I want to further define a function which calls the above method. I have noticed that the code works when I redo a try-except statement I do not really understand (see below).

```
def get_airlines_per_route(airlines_dict, source, target, max_intermediate_stops):
    lst = []

    for airline in airlines_dict.values():

        try:
            path = airline.get_route(source, target)
            if (len(path) - 2) <= max_intermediate_stops:
                lst.append(airline)

        except:
            NoSuchFlight

    return lst
```

However, I have no idea why this works. Anyway is my code correct? And moreover, how would you guys have tackled this problem?

Thanks for any advice.

Update:

The user-defined exception:

```
class NoSuchFlight(Exception):
    pass
```

Intended way:

```
def get_airlines_per_route(airlines_dict, source, target, max_intermediate_stops):
    lst = []

    for airline in airlines_dict.values():

        path = airline.get_route(source, target)
        if (len(path) - 2) <= max_intermediate_stops:
            lst.append(airline)

    return lst
```

Comment: Its difficult to understand what you mean. What is: `redo a try-except`? How do you know this **works**? And no your code is not correct. Perhaps you meant `except NoSuchFlight: pass`

Comment: btw Please fix your indentation. Python is very sensitive to indentation as are python programmers.

Comment: Okay so indentation fixed and the exception added (indentation was not the problem). It works because when I run it, the output is correct. Basically I just want to use the method in my function but I do not understand why I could not write the intended way (see update).

Comment: Well it **is** a problem when you post to stackoverflow, since that is the only source we get to see. We can't imagine what *you* get to see, so please be careful to post exactly what you have and check it in the preview before posting.

Comment: Maybe now the issue has become more clear

Comment: Yes, see the answer from @kederrac. You need the `try: except:` within `get_airlines_per_route()` to catch the `NoSuchFlight` exceptions thrown from `get_route()` otherwise `get_airlines_per_route()` will pass that exception upwards and you won't see the list returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but you should not have code like that.

In the inner function you raise a custom exception in abnormal conditions. This part is correct, even if it is more common to encapsulate the original error for eventual further analysis. So I would probably use:

```
except (nx.NetworkXNoPath, nx.NodeNotFound) as e:
    raise NoSuchFlight(e)
```

The outer code is really weird: `except:` will catch any exception. This is bad practice because you should not catch exception that you do not intend to process. For example, an IO error because of a physical disk problem should probably not be ignored.

And the following line, `NoSuchFlight` is close to a no-op: it just names an exception. You can try to type `Exception` in a python interpretor and it will just display the class name:

```
>>> Exception
<class 'Exception'>
```

without raising anything...

If you just want to ignore erroneous routes, you should use:

```
def get_airlines_per_route(airlines_dict, source, target, max_intermediate_stops):
    lst = []

    for airline in airlines_dict.values():
       try:
           path = airline.get_route(source, target)
           if (len(path) - 2) <= max_intermediate_stops:
               lst.append(airline)
       catch  NoSuchFlight:          # just skip in case of a NoSuchFlight
           pass

    return lst
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you.
This made things way more clear.

Answer (score 2):

the second `try except` will catch all the `Exceptions` this why your code is working, I suggest to use:

```
try:
    path = airline.get_route(source, target)
    if (len(path) - 2) <= max_intermediate_stops:
        lst.append(airline)

except NoSuchFlight:
    # log or something else
```

Comment: So in this case I would still like do raise my NoSuchFlight exception in case I get the NoSuchFlight exception. However, this seems very redundant to me.

Comment: you could use : raise NoSuchFlight instead of  `# log or something else`